# Implement Hashmap with different value types in Kotlin

Tags: hashmap, kotlin

Is it possible to have a hashmap in Kotlin that takes different value types?

I've tried this:

```
val template = "Hello {{world}} - {{count}} - {{tf}}"

val context = HashMap<String, Object>()
context.put("world", "John")
context.put("count", 1)
context.put("tf", true)
```

... but that gives me a type mismatch (apparantly `"John"`, `1` and `true` are not Objects)

In Java you can get around this by creating types `new String("John")`, `new Integer(1)`, `Boolean.TRUE`, I've tried the equivalent in Kotlin, but still getting the type mismatch error.

```
context.put("tf", Boolean(true))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In Kotlin, [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) is the supertype of all the other types, and you should replace Java `Object` with it:

```
val context = HashMap<String, Any>()
context.put("world", "John")
context.put("count", 1)
context.put("tf", true)
```

Answer (score 5):

For new visitors,It can also be done with this

```
val a= hashMapOf<Any,Any>( 1 to Exception(), 2 to Throwable(), Object() to 33)
```

Where both keys and values can be of any type.